# Do instances of discord.py objects stay in sync to reality?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm building a discord bot with discord.py.
I'm writing a test that adds a reaction to a Message using the `add_reaction` method.
My Message instance is not reflecting the changes, though they are visible in the server. I've added a refresh of the instance to the test to get around it.

My question is: do the instances of messages (or other classes) need to be refreshed on each use to match the most recent state in the guild or do they sync on their own?

Thanks!

Comment: Instances are not updated in discord.py once you have assigned them to a variable as there is nothing in place to update them. Also most use cases does not require automatic 'renewal' of Instances, if anything that would add on to be an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't update automatically. You'll have to use `channel.history` to read the updated messages. More [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20history#discord.DMChannel.history).